# jQuery Infinite Scroll - How to get other elements on next page?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

So let's say I'm infinite scrolling inside a div with a class of `blogroll` on my Wordpress Blog.

Is there anyway to get a different element on the next page in the infinite scroll callback function? Like an element that is somewhere else in page 2's body and then `clone()` it into the current page?

**UPDATE 1**

My function:

```
$('.blogroll').infinitescroll({ 
    loading: {
        selector: '.infinite-scroll-loading',
        msgText: 'Loading',
        img: templateDir + '/images/gif-load.gif',
        finishedMsg: "No More Posts",
        finished: function(obj){    
            console.log(obj);
            if (obj.state.isDone == true) {
                $('.load-more').html('No More Posts<span class="bar"></span>');
            } else {
                $('.load-more').html('Load More<span class="bar"></span>');
            }
        }       
    },
    navSelector  : ".post-navigation",            
    nextSelector : ".post-navigation a:first",    
    itemSelector : "article.post",
    errorCallback: function(obj) {
        if (obj == 'done') {
            $('.load-more').html('No More Posts<span class="bar"></span>');
        }
    }      
},
function(newElements, data, url) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I seemed to have fixed this temporarily by editing [jquery.infinitescroll.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js) core.

I added this to the very beginning of the `_loadcallback` function, after line 335:

```
var pageBuilderStyles = $(data).filter('#siteorigin-panels-grids-wp_footer');
$('body').append(pageBuilderStyles);
```

Nothing to make you cringe like having to edit core files though. I can't seem to find access to the raw html response in my custom callback above.

Comment: is it on page 2 of your api? or have you preloaded all the elements?

Comment: @Puzzle84 I've updated with a code sample. I'm not using any API, just the default infinitescroll function that hits /page/2 of my blog.